# Find the involutions in the indefinite orthogonal group O(2,1)

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, involutions

I would like to find the (linear) involutions that conserve the quadratic form $x^2+y^2-z^2$.

Finding reasonable equations for the entries of the matrix is possible, but not particularly nice or enlightening. Alternatively, I could start with the fact that involutions are similar to one of four matrices, but I could not use that to find a satisfying description, either.

I would be happy both with a full answer or advice on what kind of description I could reasonably expect.

Comment: If an involution preserves the quadratic form, it preserves its null cone.

Comment: Are you aware of this article http://www.dmi.usherb.ca/~charette/recherche/charette.pdf ?